# タスクキル（アプリの再起動）をしてもアプリ内のTextFieldの文字を保持しておきたい

Tags: swift

### 前提

Swiftを勉強し始めた初心者です。

[YouTubeの動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZKZCNqR7xI)を参考にメモウィジェットアプリを作成しました。

機能としましては、アプリ内のTextFieldに文字を入力すると、入力した文字がウィジェットに表示されるアプリです。

[image: イメージ説明]
[image: イメージ説明]

### 実現したいこと

アプリをタスクキルすると、Widgetに表示されている文字は表示されたままなのですが、アプリ内のTextFieldの文字が消えてしまいます。
そのため、タスクキルをしてもTextFieldの文字を保持できるようにしたいです。

[image: イメージ説明]
[image: イメージ説明]

### 試したこと

info.plistに値を追加する方法を試しても解決できませんでした。

[バックグラウンドで動くアプリが終了されたタイミングでアラートを出す](https://koogawa.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/01/21/010008)

### 該当のソースコード

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtText: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        storeData(text: "メモを入力しよう")
    }

    @IBAction func btnStoreText(_ sender: Any) {
        storeData(text: txtText.text ?? "--")
    }
    
    func storeData(text : String) {
        let storedata = StoreData(showText: text)
        let primaryData = PrimaryData(storeData: storedata)
        primaryData.encodeData()
    }
}
```

WidgetExtension.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    @AppStorage("CreateWidget", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.isseiueda")) var primaryData : Data = Data()
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        let storeData = StoreData(showText: "-")
        return SimpleEntry(storeData : storeData, configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        guard let storeData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StoreData.self, from: primaryData) else {
            return
        }
        let entry = SimpleEntry(storeData: storeData, configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
//        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
//
//        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
//        let currentDate = Date()
//        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
//            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
//            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)
//            entries.append(entry)
//        }
        guard let storeData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StoreData.self, from: primaryData) else {
            return
        }
        let entry = SimpleEntry(storeData: storeData, configuration: configuration)
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date = Date()
    let storeData : StoreData
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct WidgetExtensionEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.storeData.showText)
    }
}

struct WidgetExtension: Widget {
    let kind: String = "WidgetExtension"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetExtensionEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct WidgetExtension_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let storeData =  StoreData(showText: "-")
    static var previews: some View {
        WidgetExtensionEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(storeData: storeData, configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
}
```

StoreData.swift

```
import Foundation

struct StoreData : Codable {
    var showText : String
}
```

PrimaryData.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct PrimaryData {
    @AppStorage("CreateWidget", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.isseiueda")) var primaryData : Data = Data()
    let storeData : StoreData
    
    func encodeData() {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(storeData) else {
            return
        }
        primaryData = data
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 問題１(supportedFamiliesがない)

```swift
struct WidgetExtension: Widget {
  let kind: String = "WidgetExtension"
  
  var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
      WidgetExtensionEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    .description("This is an example widget.")
    .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
  }
}
```

### 問題2(@AppStorageの使い方が異なる)

getSnapshot, getTimelineは適切なタイミングでOS側が呼ぶので、@AppStorageで常に監視することはおそらく難しいです。ウィジェットでは

```swift
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
  func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
    let storeData = StoreData(showText: "placeholder")
    return SimpleEntry(storeData : storeData, configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
  }
  
  func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
    guard let primaryData = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.isseiueda")?.data(forKey: "CreateWidget") else { return }
    
    guard let storeData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StoreData.self, from: primaryData) else {
      return
    }
    
    let entry = SimpleEntry(storeData: storeData, configuration: configuration)
    completion(entry)
  }
  
  func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    guard let primaryData = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.isseiueda")?.data(forKey: "CreateWidget") else { return }
    
    guard let storeData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StoreData.self, from: primaryData) else {
      return
    }
    let entry = SimpleEntry(storeData: storeData, configuration: configuration)
    
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
    completion(timeline)
  }
}
```

### 問題3(メイン画面)

UIKitがわからないのでSwiftUIで書きましたが、テキストが変更されるたびに`WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`を実行することで、ウィジェット側でデータを再取得させています。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var storeData: StoreData
  
  init() {
    guard let data = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.isseiueda1")?.data(forKey: "CreateWidget") else {
      self.storeData = .init(showText: "text")
      return
    }
    
    if let storeData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StoreData.self, from: data) {
      self.storeData = storeData
    } else {
      self.storeData = .init(showText: "text")
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    TextField("Text", text: $storeData.showText)
      .onChange(of: storeData) { newValue in
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { return }
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.isseiueda")?.set(data, forKey: "CreateWidget")
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
      }
  }
}

struct StoreData : Codable, Equatable {
  var showText : String
}
```